# Test speed of my network card

Tags: lan, network-adapter

can I test wether the network card in my laptop can theoratically transfer 1gbit/s without other devices like routers or other computers?
Something  liek sending data to myself maybe?

Comment: I do this by transferring a very large file (virtual machine) and measuring the throughput speed with DU Meter.

Answer (score 1):

You may only test the real speed in your local network by doing data transfer.
There are many
[utilities](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/network-benchmark-test-your-network-speed/)
for doing that.

Testing within your computer won't do it, as the `localhost` adapter
works within the computer's memory, doing in-memory transfers,
without using at all the network adapter.

The best you can do is open the adapter's Properties to find its rated
speed. Or you may use PowerShell to get the speeds of all your adapters:

```
Get-NetAdapter | select interfaceDescription, name, status, linkSpeed
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's NTTTCP is a great tool for speed.  There is a Windows and Linux version.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-bandwidth-testing